# Emacs frozen with message "Loading Compile...Done"

Tags: python, emacs, python-3.x, python-3.3

I am using emacs to write Python code. However sometimes Emacs gets frozen with the message "Loading Compile...Done" at the bottom of the editor. I won't be able to make changes to the file or execute any commands when this happens.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I agree, @JSON. Reopening.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs may be in a loop: Typing C-g may get you out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that emacs is actually able to run Python or whichever compiler you are trying to invoke using compilation mode. If it is python try:

- Giving the full path to the python executable.
- Installing the executable with a path with no spaces especially on windows.